# Node build from Makefile only if source changed

Tags: node.js, makefile

I'm trying to build a simple Makefile for a project using Node.JS and Babel to transpile ES2015. Here's what I have so far for a `build` task:

```
build:
    .node_modules/.bin/babel $(SRC) --out-dir $(DIST) --experimental
```

What I'm curious about is how/if I can use Make's targets to only build if the contents of `$(SRC)` have changed?

Answer (score 2):

`Can I use Make's targets to only build if the contents of $(SRC) have changed?`

**Yes**

In a makefile, there's a simple way to do this, it's called a `prerequisite`.

**Try this:**

```
build: $(SRCS)
     .node_modules/.bin/babel $(SRC) --out-dir $(DIST) --experimental
```

**Explanation:**

When deciding whether or not to run the `build` target, make will evaluate whether `build`(the target) is 'out of date'. The `build` target is 'out of date' if `build` is missing, or older than the files in $(SRCS).

*"The idea is that the contents of the target file are computed based on information in the prerequisites, so if any of the prerequisites changes, the contents of the existing target file are no longer necessarily valid."*
[GNU Makefile Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html)

**Makefile Rules Reference:**

```
targets : prerequisites 
        recipe
```

Comment: I gave that a shot and it still builds every time, my `SRC = ./src`, do I need to be more specific, i.e. add some name pattern to it?

Comment: Tried that, still not working, here's my Makefile: https://github.com/Fluidbyte/node-template/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Yes, probably so. Try $(wildcard src/*.js)

Comment: Still the same, runs the build every time :(

Comment: Did you try this:  `build: $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.js)`

Comment: yeah, I've tried several variations, nothing seems to stop it from running. I'm testing it on `install` as well to see if I can prevent that from running without changes to the `package.json`

Comment: reading the docs, is it that build is a phony and not an actual file target?